# Как заполнить таблицы даными в SQL при связи 1 к многим?

Tags: sql

Например, есть таблица "Заказ" и таблица "Покупатель", связь от покупателя к заказам 1 к многим, как в таком случае заполнить поле "заказ" в таблице "покупатель" ? Если покупатель например сделала 2 заказа, то нам нужно в таблице покупатель создавать 2 строки с даными ?

```
|id|Покупатель|Заказ|
------------------
|1 |Покупат. 1|Зак.1|
|2 |Покупат. 1|Зак.2|
|3 |Покупат. 2|Зак.3|
|4 |Покупат. 2|Зак.4|

|id|Заказ|
------------------
|1 |Зак.1|
|2 |Зак.2|
|3 |Зак.3|
|4 |Зак.4|
```

Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Что-то не совсем так. Покупатель - `id|покупатель`, Заказ - `id|покупатель_id|заказ`.

Comment: а есть разница ?

Comment: А вы её не видите? В таблице покупателей не должно быть информации о заказе. В таблице заказы должна быть информации о покупателе. Теперь сравните со своей структурой

Comment: понял ошибку, спасибо за совет,  но всё же вопрос в другом, если мне нужно создать связь один к многим, то нужно ли делать для каждого случая новую строку с данными? например в учителя может быть аж 30 учеников, тогда нужно будет создать 30 строк в таблице учителя?

Comment: Если хочется извращений - то хоть через запятую в текстовом поле.. если нет - то как в первом комментарии

Comment: Есть связь один ко многим( в табилце где "многие" содержится поле с указанием ссылки на того где "один") есть связь многие ко многим(заводится отдельная таблица для связей)

Comment: Если вас смущает, что в таблице `Заказ` поле `покупатель_id` попадаются дубликаты, то не напрасно. Это вполне нормально и правильно

Comment: У меня просто как раз ситуация с учителем и учениками(такой вариант лабораторной роботы попался). В таком случае придеться заполнить ооочень много строк, потому что у меня в базе есть несколько учителей, и у каждого учителя свои ученики(минимум 10). Я должен буду придумать для всех учеников имена, а мне не хотелось бы придумывать 50 разных имен))) думал смогу както схитрить, но придеться заниматься рутиной. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Для учителя и учеников должна быть связь Многие-ко-Многим. Ибо у одного ученика много учителей, а у одного учителя много учеников

Comment: Я ввел негласное правило что в мою школу можно будет записать одновременно только на один курс, поэтому у  ученика только один учитель может быть